# Grep a set of files line by line?

Tags: unix, grep, command-line-interface

I have:

`ids`, a set of lines I want to search for, and

`type1_data`, `type2_data`, etc., a set of files I want to search through.

If I run `grep -f candidate_ids type*`, the result is returned in the format of

```
type1  id_1  a
type1  id_2  b
type1  id_3  c
type2  id_1  1
type2  id_2  2
type2  id_3  3
```

How can I get the results returned so they look like

```
type1  id_1  a
type2  id_1  1
type1  id_2  b
type2  id_2  2
type1  id_3  c
type2  id_3  3
```

? I can write a script to parse the results, but I'd prefer a command-line way of doing it, if it's possible.

Comment: Does "grep -f candidate_ids type* | sort -k 2,2" work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sort the results by the second field using:

```
grep -f candidate_ids type* | sort -k 2,2
```